# MySQL : How to dynamically call stored procedures when inserting new row in table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query that dynamically convert rows into column when inserting new row in table. However, every time I inserting new row in table I need to call the stored procedure to show the output `call bian_test_db.new_procedure();`. How can I make it automatically show the new insert data in view without calling the procedure.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'ifnull(SUM(case when itemname = ''',
      itemname,
      ''' then itemvalue end),0) AS ',
      itemname
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  bian_test_db.history;
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE view testing as SELECT user_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM bian_test_db.history 
                   GROUP BY user_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Answer (score 1):

First create below procedure

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN
SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'ifnull(SUM(case when itemname = ''',
      itemname,
      ''' then itemvalue end),0) AS ',
      itemname
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM
  bian_test_db.history;
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE OR REPLACE view testing as SELECT user_id, ', @sql, ' 
                  FROM bian_test_db.history 
                   GROUP BY user_id');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

And then create below trigger,which call above Procedure from it.

```
DELIMITER  $$
CREATE  TRIGGER CHANGE_ROW_YOUR_TABLE 
   AFTER INSERT ON YOUR_TABLE
   FOR EACH ROW    
 BEGIN
    call new_procedure;

 END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I tried that its not working  whenever I tried to insert in my history table I got an error 1336: Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger

Comment: `SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).`. See [C.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html). The stored procedure is called in the context of the trigger.

Comment: @BGTabulationBGTabulate I had tried above code,and then only put it here.It's working for me.
Did you trying same in `MySQL`?

Comment: Yea I tried same, I also read prepared statement cannot use in triggers. I just execute it in my PHP script anyway. But would be better if direct into my database sad.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER your_trigger_name AFTER INSERT ON your_table 
   FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN 
           .... your code 
   END
```

see  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html  and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html